# How to login to postgreSQL at the top level?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have Postgres 9.6 installed on mac os. When I enter the command:

```
$ psql   (it takes me to below prompt)

bar=#

bar=# \conninfo
You are connected to database "bar" as user "bar" via socket in "/tmp" at port "5432".
```

How do I get out of database bar and be at the top level so that when I enter command:

```
CREATE DATABASE postgis_in_action;
CREATE SCHEMA ch07;
CREATE TABLE ch07.bag_o_rasters(rid serial primary key, rast_name text, rast raster);
```

database postgis_in_action will be created and within this database ch07 schema will be created  and not nested inside database "bar" and the table will be created within ch07 schema under  postgis_in_action  database?

Comment: do you want to create a schema in database `bar` or you want to create a database with name `ch07`

Comment: A schema is something different than a database.

Comment: `psql -h myhost -d mydb -U myuser` this is how you can log in postgresql for perticular database. Just replcae **mydb** with your database name **ch07**.

Comment: Sorry about this confusion. I edited the question by adding the line CREATE DATABASE postgis_in_action;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating the new database you need to *switch* to it. Otherwise the `create schema` will be run in the database to which you initially connected. In `psql` you can do that using `\connect`

```
bar=# CREATE DATABASE postgis_in_action;
bar=# \connect postgis_in_action
You are now connected to database "postgis_in_action" as user "postgres".
CREATE SCHEMA ch07;
CREATE TABLE ch07.bag_o_rasters(rid serial primary key, rast_name text, rast raster);
```

I would strongly recommend you create a regular user to do your work. Do **not** do everything as the superuser. E.g.:

```
bar=# create user ace password '*******';
bar=# create CREATE DATABASE postgis_in_action owner ace;
\connect postgis_in_action ace
Password for user ace:
You are now connected to database "postgis_in_action" as user "ace".
postgis_in_action=>
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have an experience with other databases, but this is the Postgres. Schemas are nested in databases, and you cannot to connect to schema (in Postgres). If you want create the database, then you use `CREATE DATABASE ch07` instead `CREATE SCHEMA ch06`.

```
Instance (Postgres Cluster)
        |
        v
 -------------------- ...
 |            |
 v            v
Database1   Database2
 |
 ----------------------- ...
 |         |       |  
 v         v       v
public   schema1   schema2
 |
 ----------------------- ...
 |          |          |
 v          v          v
table1     table2     table3
```

In this case the Postgres is similar to MS SQL, and very different to Oracle. Schema in Postgres and Oracle are different things.

When you connect to Postgres, then you have to specify target database. You cannot to connect just to server, or you cannot to connect to schema. Schemas (in Postgres) are like directories. You can specify an order of searching of schemas. You can set `SEARCH_PATH` per connect, per user or in an session (it is analogy of `PATH` in MS Win or UNIX).

Comment: Schema is the same thing in Oracle and PostgreSQL. The difference is that schemas can only be created with `CREATE USER` and ownership is tied to the name.